# Possible to mypy typehint a method that takes a `cls` argument rather than `self`?

Tags: mypy

I'm curious if it's possible to get mypy to understand that some method in a class takes a `cls` argument rather than a `self` argument. The concrete use-case I have in mind is typing a sqlalchemy `hybrid_property`'s `.expression` decorator, but a simpler example would be trying to implement a custom/non-built-in version of `classmethod`.

Applying an explicit type annotation to `cls` doesn't work, e.g.

```
from typing import Type

class Example:
  @my_custom_classmethod
  def foo(cls: Type["Example"]) -> str:
    return "doesn't work"
```

Mypy complains that `The erased type of self "Type[Example]" is not a supertype of its class "Example"`, which, ok, I guess often makes sense, but it doesn't make sense here :/

The best solution I've managed to come up with so far is to just `# type: ignore` the method's signature:

```
class Example:
  @my_custom_classmethod
  def foo(cls: Type["Example"]) -> str: # type: ignore
    return "this actually kind of does work!"
```

This actually does seem to basically work, insofar as `cls` has the right type in the body of the method and the decorator receives a method of the right type, but it feels a bit hacky.

Answer (score 1):

`bind_self` is a method that checks and assigns `self` (`cls`) type. It relies on `is_classmethod` node flag (implementation [here](https://github.com/python/mypy/blob/e93be734f4ca51f88f0b46e5c089014e712e1d11/mypy/typeops.py#L227=)).

Flag `is_classmethod` is set during semantic analysis [here](https://github.com/python/mypy/blob/0054046c8c147a5190769bde21eb08615c16038e/mypy/semanal.py#L1064=). It is done by direct comparison of decorator and `builtins.classmethod`. So your `custom_classmethod` is not considered `classmethod`.

So you cannot produce decorator that will be equivalent to `classmethod` builtin. However, you can overcome this problem using custom descriptor:

```py
from __future__ import annotations
from typing import Callable, Concatenate, Generic, ParamSpec, TypeVar, TYPE_CHECKING

_T = TypeVar('_T')
_R = TypeVar('_R')
_P = ParamSpec('_P')


if TYPE_CHECKING:
    base = classmethod
else:
    class base(Generic[_R], classmethod):
        pass
    
class my_classmethod(base[_R], Generic[_P, _R]):
    @property
    def __func__(self) -> Callable[Concatenate[_T, _P], _R]:
        return super().__func__
    def __init__(self: my_classmethod[_P, _R], f: Callable[Concatenate[_T, _P], _R], /) -> None:
        super().__init__(f)
    def __get__(self, obj: _T, type: type[_T] | None = None) -> Callable[_P, _R]:
        return super().__get__(obj, type)
        
    
class A:
    @my_classmethod
    def foo(cls, x: int) -> str:
        return str(x)

reveal_type(A.foo(1))  # N: Revealed type is "builtins.str"
reveal_type(A().foo(1))  # N: Revealed type is "builtins.str"
A.foo('a')  # E: Argument 1 has incompatible type "str"; expected "int"
```

This works on runtime and passes type checking. Descriptors are funny. I'm assuming `python >= 3.10` and recent enough `mypy`: older python versions may require some changes (at least imports from `typing_extensions`), old `mypy` can have troubles with full descriptor support. And yes, you can inherit from `classmethod`. If you don't want, you'll have to re-implement `__get__` and `__init__` anyway (and `__func__` property if you like consistency). Remember that in 3.10 and later `classmethod` also has `wrapped` property.

Here's [playground](https://mypy-play.net/?mypy=latest&python=3.10&flags=strict%2Ccheck-untyped-defs%2Cwarn-incomplete-stub%2Cwarn-redundant-casts%2Cwarn-return-any%2Cwarn-unreachable%2Cwarn-unused-configs%2Cwarn-unused-ignores&gist=755df18c2c0d78fb659044d76664af3a) with this code.

Comment: Amazing—this has opened my eyes, thank you!

Comment: Ah, shoot, but I think `cls` is still inferred with the wrong type, `A` rather than `Type[A]`.

Comment: Ough, I should've mentioned that initially, will update my answer to spell that explicitly. That is `mypy` limitation (see refs in first two paragraphs), it takes only `builtins.classmethod` and `builtins.staticmethod` as decorators that modify `self`/`cls`/`mcs` binding, you have nothing to do with this design. You can stack your decorator with classmethod instead of reimplementing it, `mypy` will be happy. Only a few names are "special" (for property it is `builtins.property`, `abc.abstractproperty` and `functools.cached_property`, but property is easier to express in terms of descriptors).

Comment: The problem is that `cls` / `self` is **not** included into signature. `mypy` treats it specially - but not always for some reason, so we need `Concatenate` for original function. I don't completely understand whole implementation, of course, but you have really no way to return callable with `self` replaced with `cls`.